# JQuery Mobile, themeroller, gradient background is not full screen

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, background, gradient, themeroller

I am trying to create a page using JQuery mobile,
I used Themeroller to make it look as I want. The background I used is a gradient, but it doesn't go fullscreen, unless there's enough content on the page to fill the whole screen.
See image below:

[image]

See how the gradient doesn't go to the bottom of the page? That's what I've been stuck on...

I use the CSS files generated by Themeroller. I tried editing it but it's massive and I have got no clue where and what to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the background is being applied to the `.ui-content` element which is not 100% of its container's height. You could either:

1. make the `.ui-content` element 100% height or ...
2. you can set the gradient on the `.ui-page` element rather than the `.ui-content` element(s).

I would set the gradient as the `.ui-page` background like so:

```
.ui-mobile .ui-page .ui-content {
    background : none;
}
.ui-mobile .ui-page {
    background : /*gradient here*/;
}
```

Those rules should be specific enough to override the jQuery Mobile stylesheet. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YeTdT/

If you need help creating a cross-browser css gradient, see ColorZilla: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/